# Automate copying between same places of similar directory trees

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I am maintaining large filesystem tree on two machines and ofter need to copy one or few files from one to another.

Is it possible to automate copying between same places of two trees and void need to type long identical paths?

---

For example, I am in `myroot/a/b/c` and want to copy file to `remoteroot/a/b/c` without specifying `a/b/c`.

Something like this:

```
myroot/a/b/c$: smartcopy myfile --destination-root remoteroot
```

Comment: Yes, almost certainly. Please provide some examples in your question of what you want to achieve. Also identify whether copies should be bi-directional, or if one machine is always the master.

Comment: It seems you don't mean "automate", as in copying files automatically, but rather "simplify", as in copying files manually but without specifiying all the usual detail. Have I understood correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The `rsync` utility has the `-R` option that can somewhat help you here, but you need to pass the *whole* source path *and* inform `rsync` about what part of the source path you want to consider as the "root" piece. You provide that information by inserting a `./` in the wanted point of the source path.

In your example the "root" piece is just `myroot/`, so your command would be like:

```bash
myroot/a/b/c$ rsync -R myroot/./a/b/c/myfile remoteroot
```

I assume you'd wish to have an easy way for specifying the "root" piece out of the current directory path on any complex case.

A robust yet still relatively simple way would be by path depth number. For instance, on `bash` you could do something like:

```bash
/path/to/myroot/a/b/c$ rsync -R "$(idx=4; IFS=/; set -- $PWD ; printf '%s/' "${@:1:idx}" . "${@:idx+1}")"/myfile remoteroot
                                 #     ^--- 4th piece of path counted as number of slashes in $PWD
```

Certainly not terse as a one-liner, but that Command Substitution could be rather made a function in your `.bashrc` file, like:

```bash
rootidx() {
    local idx="$1"

    # make Bash perform Word Splitting on / character
    local IFS=/ # make IFS local here, so to not affect global IFS

    # set function's arguments to each piece of current directory path,
    # as split on $IFS
    set -- $PWD

    # print from first argument up to the one indicated by wanted index,
    # then a ./, then from wanted index onwards
    printf '%s/' "${@:1:idx}" . "${@:idx+1}"
}
```

to be used like:

```bash
/path/to/myroot/a/b/c$ rsync -R "$(rootidx 4)"/myfile remoteroot
```

Alternatively, to pinpoint the "root" at a specified *string* of the full path, a simple and also POSIX-compliant way might be like:

```bash
/path/to/myroot/a/b/c$ rsync -R "${PWD%%/myroot/*}/myroot/./${PWD#*/myroot/}"/myfile remoteroot
```

which uses a Parameter Expansion over `$PWD` to inject the `./` at the point where the `myroot` piece of string first occurs in the current directory path.

However, as fairly simple as that Parameter Expansion is, you need to be careful to specify a *matching intermediate* piece of the current directory path, otherwise that particular expansion won't work as intended and will instead concatenate the whole current directory with itself and the specified string in the middle.

That Parameter Expansion can be made a function too, which also helps at making it a bit more robust, like in:

```bash
rootname() {
    [[ "$PWD" == */"$1"/* ]] && \  # check presence of string as intermediate path
        printf '%s' "${PWD%%/${1}/*}/${1}/./${PWD#*/${1}/}" || \  # apply the injection, or
        printf '%s -not valid-' "$1"   # try to produce an unlikely filename so to make `rsync` fail
}
```

to be used like:

```bash
/path/to/myroot/a/b/c$ rsync -R "$(rootname myroot)"/myfile remoteroot
```

Lastly, if you have GNU tools as well as a shell that understands `**` pathname expansion, you could use these functions for local copy operations with `cp` too. For instance like:

```bash
/path/to/myroot/a/b/c$ (shopt -s globstar; cd "$(rootidx 4)" && cp --parents **/myfile otherpath)
```

The `shopt -s globstar` command makes `bash` enable `**` expansion.

Naturally you could make that a function too:

```bash
smartcp() {
    # FIXME: some sanity checks over arguments here
    # TODO: detect type of first argument, and use either rootidx or rootname accordingly
    (shopt -s globstar; cd "$(rootidx "$1")" && cp --parents **/"${2}" "$3")
}
```

so then:

```bash
/path/to/myroot/a/b/c$ smartcp 4 myfile otherpath
```